# opencv match triangular facets

Tags: opencv, matching, feature-detection, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

I am trying to calibrate multiple cameras and one of the steps involves matching 3d triangular facets using RANSAC.n (subject is a circular object - not a planar chessboard)

I am looking for an opencv method that will allow me to do this. I looked at FindHomography but that only works on points, I am looking for a method that allows triangles to be passed in for matching.

Comment: Not perfect, but at least a step: Take the corner point of your triangles, and match them to the corresponding corner points of your goal.